# Maya - How to update file name displayed on menu bar after renaming the scene

Tags: python, filenames, maya

Using this command:

```
cmds.file(rename = "newName.mb")
```

Doesn't display the new name in the menu bar on the top of the window. It still displays the old name but adding an asterisk * to show it has been changed.

The problem is this is confusing for the user. The file will be saved in a different path, but you don't know until you do it.

How can I update the name displayed on top, if rename doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PySide to achieve this, it is natively shipped with Maya since version 2014. You can customize pretty much everything in Maya using Pyside.

**Here's the code to change the window title:**

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from maya import OpenMayaUI as omui
from shiboken import wrapInstance

def getMayaWindow():
    omui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()    
    ptr = omui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return wrapInstance(long(ptr), QtGui.QWidget)

newPath = r"C:\Users\pfruchet\Desktop\NewSceneName.ma"

mayaWindow = getMayaWindow()

print mayaWindow.windowTitle() #Prints the window title with your original scene path
cmds.file(rename = newPath)
print mayaWindow.windowTitle() #Prints the window title with your original scene path
print cmds.file(query=True, sn=True) #But Prints C:/Users/pfruchet/Desktop/NewSceneName.ma ---> Scene name changed but not updated in window title

mayaWindow.setWindowTitle(r"Autodesk Maya 2014: " + newPath) #here is the magic
print mayaWindow.windowTitle() #Prints Autodesk Maya 2014: C:\Users\pfruchet\Desktop\NewSceneName.ma
mayaWindow.setWindowModified(False)
```

The last line allows you to show or hide the "*" after the file path.

**Output:**

```
Autodesk Maya 2014: C:\Users\pfruchet\Desktop\OriginalScene.ma
Autodesk Maya 2014: C:\Users\pfruchet\Desktop\OriginalScene.ma
C:/Users/pfruchet/Desktop/NewSceneName.ma
Autodesk Maya 2014: C:\Users\pfruchet\Desktop\NewSceneName.ma
```

**Some references:**

[Autodesk doc: Working with PySide in Maya](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-SDK/files/GUID-3F96AF53-A47E-4351-A86A-396E7BFD6665-htm.html) How to destroy maya by adding hideous stylesheets.

[Pyside doc: QWidget](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html?highlight=qwidget#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.setWindowTitle) If you want to try other stuff (you can change the window icon apparently)

Comment: PySide natively ships from v 2014 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

I handled this by changing the selection, which forces Maya to update the titlebar (and thereby show the new filename):

```
cmds.file(rename = "newName.mb")
cur_selection = cmds.ls(sl=True)  # Save current selection
cmds.select('renderPartition')  # Select something (anything) the user doesn't already have selected
cmds.select(cur_selection)  # Restore user's selection
```